# Undefined variable,when loading a view via AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, jquery

I use ajax to dynamically load some contents for my website, it works well when loading things like register and login forms, because I don't have to send any data to the view itself(`register_view`, etc).
But, when I try to load something different, like user's profile for example, it requires me to pass some variables to the view, and here when I get in trouble with AJAX.
And I'm sure the variable I send is tested by `isset` and `!empty` in the controller,
But at the view, it suddenly become undefined variable, this only happens when accessing a profile via AJAX.
PHP code:
Controller:

```
if($this->uri->segment(4)){//if viewing a specific profile.
                /*escape the uri segment*/
                $segment = intval($this->uri->segment(4));
                if($segment == 0){//the uri segment was a string
                    /*display error message.*/
                    $data['content'] = 'redirect_message';
                    $data['information'] = 'Could\'nt find the profile!, please try again.';
                    $this->load->view('templates/manage', $data);
                }
                else{//else , the uri segment is a number, considered safer.
                    $query_result = $this->db_model->getProfile($segment);//get the Profile
                    /*check if any results were returned.*/
                    if($query_result->num_rows() > 0){
                        /*load a view to display the specified Profile.*/
                        $data['information'] = $query_result;

                        if($this->input->is_ajax_request())//requesting via ajax, display the content only.
                        $this->load->view("view_Profile_view", $query_result);
                        else{
                            $data['content'] = 'view_Profile_view';
                            $this->load->view('templates/manage', $data);

                        }
                    }
                    else{ //no rows returned.
                        /*show error message.*/
                        $data['content'] = 'redirect_message';
                        $data['information'] = 'Error viewing the Profile!';
                        $this->load->view('templates/manage',$data);
                    }
                }
            }
```

View(`view_Profile_view`):

```
/*display the profile:*/
$row = $information->row();//error occurs here!
echo $row->username.'</br>';
echo $row->email;
```

jQuery/JS code:

```
var base_url = "/";
var site_url = "/index.php/";



$(document).ready(function(){
$('.ajax_anchor').click(function(){
    loadForm(this);
    return false;
});


});
function loadForm(anchor){
    var splitted_url = $(anchor).attr('href').split("/");

    if(splitted_url.length == 7){//probably accessing /site/login or /site/register not something like /site/profiles/view/[ID].
        var url = splitted_url[splitted_url.length-2]+"/"+splitted_url[splitted_url.length-1];
        }
    else if(splitted_url.length == 9) {//probabbly accessing /site/profiles/view/[ID] not something like /site/login.
        var url=
            splitted_url[splitted_url.length-4]+"/"
            +
            splitted_url[splitted_url.length-3]+"/"
            +
            splitted_url[splitted_url.length-2]+"/"
            +
            splitted_url[splitted_url.length-1]+"/"

            ;
    }

    var csrf_token = $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name');//holding the csrf cookie generated by CodeIgniter, using jQuery cookie plugin
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: site_url+url,
          data: {csrf_test_name:csrf_token}//pass the csrf token otherwise codeigniter will return an error(500).
        }).done(function( html ) {
            var ajaxResult$ = $('#ajax_result');//ajax_result is an empty div, used to display ajax results.
            ajaxResult$.empty().append(html).dialog();//dialog:is a jquery-ui function.
        });

}
```

Comment: So where does the "undefined variable" error occur?

Comment: @Bergi Oh! I forgot the view, updating now.

Comment: Trying doing a vardump on `$information`

Comment: so I guess $information is a (error message) string... If it's a PHP error you might remove all JS and tell us just the URL, including the wrong and the expected server response.

Comment: @xbonez Well, the `$information` variable is undefined in the view, and it's a `CI_DB_mysql_result` in the controller , I dont think it has any relation with the problem , because I can access any profile without AJAX.

Comment: in your ajax request, add a error handler that looks something like this `error: function(err) { console.log(err); }`. Inspecting the object that gets logged will show you the PHP error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it your assigning  `$data['information'] = $query_result;` so `$information` object is available to the view, but instead your directly passing `$query_result` to the view and not `$data`

So change:
`$this->load->view("view_Profile_view", $query_result);`

To:
`$this->load->view("view_Profile_view", $data);`

Comment: Nice catch. Completely missed that.